# Vim PHP Tab jumping to next blank line after statement

Tags: php, vim, tabs, macvim

I'm having an odd problem with editing PHP files with macvim. When I press tab, instead of giving me a tab or series of spaces, it instead jumps down to a blank line after any series of statements. It will do this through the entire file until it reaches the end. For example, in the following snippet, if I have my cursor in front of "$products" and pressed tab, no tab or space would be inserted, and the cursor would land on the empty line below it:

```
  public function index()
  {
     // get a distinct list of product names
     $products = $this->license_model->get_all_product_names();

     // get all records and fields from the view
     $records = $this->license_model->get_all_records();

     // assign objects to the array to pass to the view
     $data = array(
        'products' => $products,
        'records' => $records
     );

     // load the view
     $this->load->view('home.php', $data);
  }
```

If I was to try and tab the comment above the $data array, the cursor would move to the line just above the next comment "load the view".

Using the vim command >> will indent the line as expected, however. The problem only seems to be with *.php files. Tabbing in say a *.java file works as normal.

Any ideas how I can fix this?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sounds like something has mapped `<Tab>` or `<C-i>` in insert mode to something.  See what maps are defined for `<Tab>` by issuing:

```
:verbose map <Tab>
```

This should output any mappings that are currently set up and which file set these mappings (so you may remove them).

Comment: It looks like snipmate might be doing something wonky. After removing the plugin everything works again. Now to figure out why snipmate decided to break. Thanks for the tip!